# docker containers not seeing each other despite created from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running Airflow 2.1.2 in localhost using:

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-python3
    image: analytics-airflow
    env_file:
      - ./environtment_config/airflow_config/airflow.env
    container_name: analytics-container-3
    volumes:
      - ./database_utils:/database_utils
      - ./maintenance:/maintenance
      - ./utils:/utils
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./datawarehouse:/datawarehouse
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
  scheduler:
    container_name: analytics-scheduler
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-python3
    env_file:
      - ./environtment_config/airflow_config/airflow.env
    volumes:
      - ./database_utils:/database_utils
      - ./maintenance:/maintenance
      - ./utils:/utils
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./datawarehouse:/datawarehouse
    ports:
      - "8793:8793"
    command: scheduler
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2-python3.8

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"

RUN pip install -r environtment_config/docker_src/requirements.pip
```

Airflow.env

```
#Execution behaviour variables
_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE=True
_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME=admin
_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD=admin
_AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE=true
#Building variables
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN= sqlite:////opt/airflow/airflow.db
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=SequentialExecutor
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__SECRET_KEY=localhost
AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING= False
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=
```

The UI shows that scheduler is not running:
[image]

If I run `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                       NAMES
1d509c71c804   airflow2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   42 minutes ago      Up 42 minutes (healthy)      8080/tcp                                    scheduler
f1a945f1df01   airflow2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   container-3
```

I achieved to fix it connecting to webserver container with:

```
docker exec -it container-3 bash
airflow scheduler
```

So the fix is to run in the same container both services but I don't understand why it doesn't work with two different container as both are created with `docker-compose` they should see each other.

Also it's important to achieve one container per service as I will be able to raise multiple scheduler containers and use HA Scheduler, and scale up the server.

Also, if both services runs in a single container logs will be mix, so it will be harded to debug if something happens in one of the services.

Any idea how to fix it? or why this is happening?

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is in database which is not shared between those two containers. If I correctly understand `/opt/airflow` is not shared volume by those two containers. I would suggest using postgres instead of sqlite for better performance and reliability.  I'm quite sure you've seen the [official docker compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html).

Comment: Might be really stupid of me to ask but is there a dependency where 1 container always starts before the dependency is resolved? Furthermore, you can explicitly mention the other container using the name in compose as it should be resolved by compose's DNS. I don't see any configuration and I have no knowledge of Airflow so I can't tell for sure. If you want to make sure you have no interference from other containers you can also opt to make a customer compose network (SEE: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: @TomaszUrbaszek That fixed the issue. You should post that as an answer and I will accept as a correct answer.

Comment: @JustLudo thanks for the answer I tried to add dependency between them in composer but not fixed. The issue is db volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not that scheduler is not communicating with webserver directly, but that you use sqlite and Sequential executor. Basically each of your containers has a separate sqlite database and scheduler and webserver communicate via the DB actually.

The warning you see is consequence of that.

In Airflow 2.1.3 you will see additional warnings about using SQLite and sequential executor in UI (though you already have warnings about in the logs).

If you want to use Airflow for anything really serious with separate contaieners and running fast (processing task in parallel), you should use Postgres or MySQL database and LocalExecutor at least. Then you will not see the warnings and Airflow will work much faster (basicaly everything should start working in parallel).

If you want some inspiration on how you can do it (including how it works when everything is separated out into separate containers per service) with DockerCompose you can take a look at our Quick-start: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html  (but this is also only for development - though it uses CeleryExecutor, so if you want to use it for anything more serious that quick-start/take a look at Airflow, then you have to make your own DockerCompose based on it).

For anything really serious - I recommend https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html instead.

Comment: Thanks @JarekPotiuk. Sharing the volume /opt/airflow between both docker containers in compose fix the issue.

I am using sqlite for local testing purposes. In production I use postgresql.

Thanks for the feedback.